# How do I add a close button on the PrimeFaces dashboard component?

Tags: button, primefaces, widget, dashboard

I am trying to create widgets using the PrimeFaces `dashboard` component. According to user choice, he should be able to collapse / close the widget. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you are just looking for a widget with toggle functionality, why haven't you used `<p:accordionPanel> ` ?

Comment: @dShringi - The widgets must also have the close and edit functionality. I want to provide this with dashboard.(Something like what iGoogle gadgets have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closable panels in your dashboard items;

```
 <p:panel id="pnl" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel">
```

Good Luck!

Comment: ThankYou! Now the widgets can be toggled and closed!